# Why does everyone think I'm using IE6?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, internet-explorer-6

Firefox 3.5.1 installed, but whatbrowser.org thinks that I'm using IE6 - as does twitter and youtube. I've reinstalled Firefox and disabled AddOns, but it is still registering as IE6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type "About:config" in the address bar, and check for a setting called "general.useragent.override." If it's there, delete it.

If it's not there, make sure you don't have a plugin like "[useragentswitcher](http://chrispederick.myacen.com/work/firefox/useragentswitcher/)" or [useragentbar](http://uabar.mozdev.org.)" installed.

Comment: This fixed it - thank you! (now if I can only remember why I set that to begin with...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are at a school or work it could be the result of a proxy they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the useragent. Sometimes, I've seen browsers that are IE 8, but have something in their UA that says something similar to, `IE6 compatible`, which the server treats as higher priority than the real browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers above:
about:config useragent, any useragent switching plugins, and possibly a proxy.

You can try to debug this by checking your headers going out.  Try LiveHeaders.  Check the UserAgent in the request.  If it's straight Mozilla, you have a proxy.  If it's not (says IE (compatible Mozilla) or whatever, you have changed your settings.